Proof that HALF-3SAT is in P

We are told that assume that P $\neq$ NP ,
and that one of these languages is in P and the other one does not belong to P.
I have managed to polynomially reduce 3SAT to FIRST-HALF-3SAT by duplicating the formula $\varphi$ and returning it,
so then $3SAT\leq_PFIRST-HALF-3SAT$ which means that if  $FIRST-HALF-3SAT\in P$ then $3SAT\in P$ but 3SAT is NP-complete, so then $P=NP$, which is a contradiction to our assumption.
Now I need help with showing that $HALF-3SAT\in P$

Any formula $\varphi$ with $n$ clauses belongs to HALF-3SAT. This is because you always have an assignment satisfying at least half of the clauses. Consider the following two assignments:

$A = \underbrace{(0, 0, \dots, 0)}_{n}$
$B = \underbrace{(1, 1, \dots, 1)}_{n}$

Each one of the clauses in $\varphi$ must be satisfied either by $A$ or $B$, or both, giving us
$$\#\{\text{satisfied clauses of }\varphi(A)\} \, + \, \#\{\text{satisfied clauses of }\varphi(B)\} \, \ge \, n$$
Now, we notice that one of the two must be $\ge \frac{n}{2}$ in order to satisfy the relation above, and thus $\varphi \in$ HALF-3SAT.

It’s perfectly possible for a clause to be satisfied by both $A$ and $B$.

Yes, consider the clause $(x_1 \lor x_2' \lor x_3)$. It is satisfied both for $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$.

But your basic idea seems valid. Let me take the liberty to correctly state it.

@EmilJeřábek you are absolutely right, thanks.

Hi @izanbf1803 is there any particular reason you edited out the followings: 'using the Pigeonhole principle' and "Also, note that the above argument works for any pair of assignments A and A′ "?

HALF-3SAT is rather easy. You simply accept all 3SAT instances. It is because, given any 3SAT instance, we can always find an assignment that satisfies more than half (even the $\frac{7}{8}$ fraction) of the clauses.
If you wish to construct one such assignment, here are a few pointers. The Karloff-Zwick algorithm shows that for any instance of 3SAT, there is an assignment that satisfies at least $\frac{7}{8}$ fraction of the clauses. Hence, the $\ge \frac{1}{2}$ constraint is trivially satisfied. If you want a simpler algorithm for just the $\ge \frac{1}{2}$ case, you can use the $\frac{1}{2}$-approximation of MAX-SAT. Both randomized and derandomized versions exist [see here].

Indeed, we don't need to use any algorithm to check; just accept all 3SAT instances. I have mentioned them for reference as well as constructing one such assignment if required.

Thanks for the feedback. I have updated my answer accordingly. :)
